# Variance of maximum likelihood estimator for discrete distribution

Tags: statistics, estimation

Lets say we have a discrete distribution with following probabilities:

$P(X=0)=\frac{1}{3}\theta, P(X=1)=\frac{2}{3}\theta, P(X=2)=\frac{2}{3}(1-\theta), P(X=3)=\frac{1}{3}(1-\theta)$

Estimating $\theta$ using maximum likelihood function is quite easy: for sample $(3,0,2,1,3,2,1,0,2,1)$ it is $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}=0.5$.

But how can we calculate (*estimate*) variance of $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}$? I don't see any straightforward way to do that using Fisher Information or just definition of variance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume one observes $n_i$ times the result $i$ in a sample of size $n=n_0+n_1+n_2+n_3$, then the likelihood of the sample  is
$$
\ell(\theta)=\theta^{n_0}(2\theta)^{n_1}(2(1-\theta))^{n_2}(1-\theta)^{n_3}3^{-n},
$$
hence
$$
\frac{\partial\log\ell(\theta)}{\partial\theta}=\frac{n_0+n_1}{\theta}-\frac{n_2+n_3}{1-\theta},
$$
which implies that the MLE estimator $\widehat\theta$ of the parameter $\theta$ based on this sample is
$$
\widehat\theta=\frac{n_0+n_1}n.
$$
Note that $n_0+n_1$ is the number of successes in $n$ i.i.d. trials when the probability of success of one trial is
$
P[X=0]+P[X=1]=\theta.
$
Thus, $n\widehat\theta$ is binomial $(n,\theta)$, hence
$$
n^2\mathrm{var}(\widehat\theta)=n\theta(1-\theta),
$$
that is,
$$
\mathrm{var}(\widehat\theta)=\frac{\theta(1-\theta)}n.
$$